# How does Batrider's tether-break and napalm work WRT his firefly ability?

Tags: dota-2

Two questions in one here guys, let me know if better to split them out:

1. If Batrider has ult'd someone and lasso'd them, under what circumstances does the lasso break? I ask as on various occasions I've seen it break, but it appears to be inconsistent, so wondering how that works. One example I've seen is if Bat uses a force-staff it can break, but sometimes it doesn't break.
2. If Batrider has applied stacks of sticky napalm to a hero, and then the hero takes damage from his firefly AoE ability - does the firefly DPS increase with napalm stacks? For example - if Bat has level 1 firefly (20 DPS) and level 1 sticky napalm (extra 10 damage), then does a hero with 1 stack of sticky napalm take 30 DPS or 20?

Thanks!

Comment: If bat uses force staff while under Firefly, it wont break as both Bat and his target gain free pathing. I don't have a list of things that break lasso, but those I can think of are usually "disjoint" spells, like Venge's swap, Wisp's Relocate (even a few units away). The answer to your 2nd question is yes, that's how Batrider used to be (still is to some extent) able to get a sub 10 min blink on the jungle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking flaming lasso requires either Batrider or the victim to travel at a speed faster than 500 unit per 0.05 sec. The distance does not matter as long as you break that speed limit.

*Exemple : if you use Lasso one someone and the Vengeful Spirit next to him uses Nether Swap on him, the lasso will break since swap is a pseudo blink and thus the swapped unit gets a really fast travel speed*

Same would apply with Relocate (Wisp), Glimpse (Disruptor), Recall (Keeper of the Light), Test of Faith (Chen) or any ability that would induce a travel time faster than 500 unit in 0.05sec. In a Similar fashion, If batrider uses Blink dagger, the lasso breaks. Forcestaff pushes a unit forward at the speed of 600 unit in 0.4 sec which is way too slow compared to the speed required to break lasso (500units/0.05sec). So by Forcestaffing, Batrider should never break its lasso.

As for your second interrogation, the damage of Firefly is dealt per second (at max level  80 per second). A "tick" of damage is applied every second and to this number is added a bonus for every Sticky Nappalm stacks on your victim.

Exemple : If you have 2 level 4 stack you will apply **80 + 2*25 = 130** Damage Per Second with Firefly. If you have 3 level 1 stack you will apply **80 + 3*10 = 110** Damage Per Second with Firefly.

Comment: Good luck on successfully recalling someone lassoed by batrider ;)

Comment: @T_O Though Highly unlikely to happen it's still possible :D

Comment: well actually batrider could be the one relocated

Comment: @T_O and flaming lasso does not deal damage so technically the victim can still be recalled if no one attacks him

Comment: I am not sure if it is the case anymore, but I remember lasso not being able to drag a target over impassable terrain.  If this is still true, does it break the lasso if you try and move too far after going to high ground victim in tow?

Comment: @turbo I don't remember it that way. Lasso does not break at terrain at least since a few years as far as I can remember.

Comment: @T_O not that unlikely, if bat lassos someone without fireflight and the enemy counterpicked a naga that uses song of the siren -> kotl can tp him home.